# Как определить какой именно файл php.ini используется в CLI

Tags: php

Я использую PHP через интерфейс командной строки (CLI).

Как определить, где находится файл `php.ini` который используется PHP в этом режиме?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начиная с версии 5.2.3 команда `php` поддерживает волшебную опцию `--ini`, которая и выводит информацию об используемых конфигурационных файлах.

Пример использования:

```
php --ini
```

Пример вывода:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/dev/php/5.2/lib  
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/dev/php/5.2/lib/php.ini  
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)  
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Эта и другие опции команды `php`, описаны в [официальной документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.commandline.options.php).